# Adding Anotation causes unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: json, swift, ios8, xcode6, mapkit

Currently working with json and mapkit, getting longitude and latitude from json.
using an array to store the json results and than having a for loop to get the longitude and latitude from the array, as seen below

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                var allContacts: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(allContactsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
                self.dataArray = allContacts as [AnyObject]

                for(self.i = 0; self.i < self.dataArray.count; self.i++){
                    println(self.dataArray[self.i])
                    var dict: NSDictionary = self.dataArray[self.i] as NSDictionary
                    self.crimeCat = dict["category"] as? String
                    self.crimeName = dict["name"] as? String
                    var crimeLat = dict["latitude"] as CLLocationDegrees //throws an error here
                    var crimeLong = dict["longitude"] as CLLocationDegrees
                    //println(self.crimeName)

                    var crimeLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(crimeLat,crimeLong)
                    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.coordinate = crimeLocation
                    annotation.title = self.crimeCat!
                    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
                println(allContacts)
```

However whenever i run the application i get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

i have added in breakpoints and the details seems to load properly

below are the followings i have tried

```
self.crimeLat = dict["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees
self.crimeLong = dict["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees


var crimeLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.crimeLat,self.crimeLong) //when i try this method i get same error here
```

I know the results returned has lat and long as i have tested it.

Any Suggestion what i may be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are `latitude` and `longitude` written the same way in your dictionary (and not something like `lat` and `lon`) ? What do you have if you `println("\(dict["latitude"])")` for example ? If it's a string and not a number you might want to do : `(dict["latitude"] as NSString).doubleValue`.

Comment: Hi you were correct the way i was pulling the data out was wrong.  Answer is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by lchamp the way i was pulling the json data was incorrect, the json was return

```
location{
  latitude = "somevalue"
  longitude = "somevalue"
}
```

i changed the below code

```
self.crimeLat = dict["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees
self.crimeLong = dict["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees
```

to

```
 self.crimeLat = ((dict["location"] as NSDictionary)["latitude"] as NSString).doubleValue
 self.crimeLong = ((dict["location"] as NSDictionary)["longitude"] as NSString).doubleValue
```

and this has now sorted out the issue.